# How to get all ones for below query between min and max dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below this query between CheckPointTimeValue min and CheckPointTimeValue max dates i want to show TimeValueBit as 1 and others as 0. How can I do that in SQL SERVER

```
SELECT C.CHECKPOINTNAME, TC.TERMINALCHECKPOINTID, CT.CheckPointTimeValue, CT.CheckPointTimeID, C.Scheduled, CT.ScheduledTimeValue
,CASE 
 WHEN CT.CheckPointTimeValue BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(CheckPointTimeValue) FROM  [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes]) AND (SELECT MAX(CheckPointTimeValue) FROM  [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes]) THEN 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS 'TimeValueBit'
 FROM [TAMS].[TerminalCheckPoints] TC
        INNER JOIN [TAMS].[CheckPoint] C ON C.CHECKPOINTID = TC.CHECKPOINTID
        LEFT JOIN [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes] CT ON CT.TerminalCheckPointID = TC.TERMINALCHECKPOINTID
        WHERE TC.TERMINALID = 1 AND TC.CHECKPOINTTYPE = 'TRUCK'
        ORDER BY C.SEQUENCENUMBER
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. What is the problem?

Comment: Between Minimum CheckPointTimeValue till Maximum CheckPointTimeValue I want to display TimeValueBit as 1 but currently since the NULL record is in between it's displaying 0 but how to display 1 between minimum and maxium checkpointtimevalue even if null is present in between

Comment: adress the null in the `CASE... WHEN CT.CheckpointTimeValue is null`

Comment: er.... Why do you even have a case statement if you want to display 1 regardless? Isn't your case statement just basically saying "if a time exists at all, then 1, else 0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT C.CHECKPOINTNAME, TC.TERMINALCHECKPOINTID, CT.CheckPointTimeValue, CT.CheckPointTimeID, C.Scheduled, CT.ScheduledTimeValue
    ,CASE 
       WHEN CT.CheckPointTimeValue BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(CheckPointTimeValue) FROM [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes]) AND (SELECT MAX(CheckPointTimeValue) FROM  [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes]) THEN 1
       ELSE 0
     END AS 'TimeValueBit'
    FROM [TAMS].[TerminalCheckPoints] TC
    INNER JOIN [TAMS].[CheckPoint] C ON C.CHECKPOINTID = TC.CHECKPOINTID
    LEFT JOIN [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes] CT ON CT.TerminalCheckPointID = TC.TERMINALCHECKPOINTID
    WHERE TC.TERMINALID = 1 AND TC.CHECKPOINTTYPE = 'TRUCK'
    ORDER BY C.SEQUENCENUMBER)

SELECT 
  CheckPointName
, TerminalCheckPointID
, CheckPointTimeValue
, CheckPointTimeID
, Scheduled
, ScheduledTimeValue
, CASE 
    WHEN TerminalCheckPointID BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(TerminalCheckPointID) FROM cte WHERE TimeValueBit = 1) AND (SELECT MAX(TerminalCheckPointID) FROM cte WHERE TimeValueBit = 1) 
      THEN 1  
      ELSE 0
    END AS TimeValueBit
FROM
 cte
```

Comment: Then all 4 records are showing as 1...But I want only those top three records to display 1....

Comment: @user1030181 Updated answer. I used a cte with your base query to figure out if terminalid fell between the two timevaluebit that were true.

Comment: This works Perfect @Sqlchao